# CName for static images - will Google crawl?

Tags: seo, cdn

I am planning to serve images on a CDN using a CNAME: images.mysite.com. I am doing this because CDNname.mysite.com makes ugly URL's and MAY be bad for SEO (debatable).

Will Google crawl the subdomain (only storing images and nothing on the main domain will link to it).

If so, would a simple robots.txt be suitable? Is this even possible seeing that the subdomain is ONLY serving images, JS, CSS i.e. not HTML?

Thanks

Comment: I answered a related question yesterday, which contains some reference links, and there's a link to a duplicate question there as well:
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49191/could-a-cdn-serving-static-images-result-in-decreased-search-engine-rankings

It would be interesting to hear people's experiences regarding this.

Comment: Google associates images on the rendering page, it doesn't care where they are hosted.

Answer (score 2):

Since the images on the subdomains would be linked from the main domain, Google will certainly be aware of the subdomain and will certainly grab the linked images.  I don't believe you will get the subdomain actively crawled as a separate entity, though.  The algorithm is smart enough to detect that you are just serving resources off the subdomain instead of actively hosting real content and index accordingly.